# Metroui with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, microsoft-metro

i have just started working with javascript.i was searching a lot on using metroui.org.ua  i am not able to consume the .js files in my html.Am missing some configuration ? any help would be appreciated. including my html file as well

```
    <head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/modern.css" /> 
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      // Load jQuery
      google.load("jquery", "1");   
  </script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tile-slider.js"></script>
  </head>
 <html>
  <div class="tile image-slider" data-role="image-slider">
  <div class="tile-content">
       <img src="../img/AngryBirds.jpg"/>
  </div>

   <div class="tile-content">
       <img src="../img/CutTheRope.jpg"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I pasted a code you can give a try in by saving it as an Html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue Might lie with the Jquery Support For winJS

Please Go through the link

[Jquery for winjS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2013/04/01/windows-store-app-support-in-jquery-version-2-0.aspx)

The version you are using might not be compatible with winJS. You might need to do some modifications. Please let me know if it worked or not.

Also try spending time reading this see if it helps

[jquery winjs](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/07/10/jquery-and-winjs-working-together-in-windows-store-apps.aspx)

Here's a code sample that I tested. and the slider is working fine. Copy paste it in a  note pad and save as an html. Then run. From the online api it is consuming the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Modern UI CSS">
    <meta name="author" content="Sergey Pimenov">
    <meta name="keywords" content="windows 8, modern style, modern ui, style, modern, css, framework">

    <link href="http://metroui.org.ua/css/modern.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://metroui.org.ua/css/theme-dark.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://metroui.org.ua/css/modern-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/assets/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/assets/google-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/assets/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/assets/github.info.js"></script>
    <script src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/modern/tile-slider.js"></script>
    <script src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/modern/start-menu.js"></script>
    <script src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/modern/tile-drag.js"></script>

    <title>Modern UI CSS</title>

    <style>
        body {
            background: #1d1d1d;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body class="metrouicss">
<div class="page secondary fixed-header">
    <div class="page-header ">
        <div class="page-header-content">
            <div class="user-login">
                <a href="http://metroui.org.ua/#">
                    <div class="name">
                        <span class="first-name">Sergey</span>
                        <span class="last-name">Pimenov</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="avatar">
                        <!--<img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/myface.jpg"/>-->
                        <i class="icon-user fg-color-white"></i>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <h1 class="fg-color-white">Start</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="page-region">
        <div class="page-region-content tiles">
            <div class="tile-group tile-drag">
                <div class="tile icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <i class="icon-calculate"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Calculator</span>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <a target="_blank" id="qq" href="http://metroui.org.ua//" onclick="console.log('clicked')" class="tile image outline-color-green">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/myface.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </a>

                <div class="tile icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/Mail128.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <div class="badge">10</div>
                        <div class="name">Mail</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile bg-color-orangeDark icon">
                    <b class="check"></b>
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/Video128.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Video</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile double image">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/5.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Pictures</span>
                        <div class="badge bg-color-orange">5</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile bg-color-green icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/Market128.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Store</span>
                        <span class="badge">6</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile bg-color-red icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/Music128.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Music</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile double bg-color-blueDark">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/michael.jpg" class="place-left"/>
                        <h3 style="margin-bottom: 5px;">michael_angiulo</h3>
                        <p>
                            I just saw Thor last night. It was awesome! I think you'd love it.
                        </p>
                        <h5>RT @julie_green</h5>

                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Tweet@rama</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile bg-color-darken icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/YouTube128.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">YouTube</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile double bg-color-green" data-role="tile-slider" data-param-period="3000">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <h2>mattberg@live.com</h2>
                        <h5>Re: Wedding Annoucement!</h5>
                        <p>
                            Congratulations! I'm really excited to celebrate with you all. Thanks for...
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <h2>tina@live.com</h2>
                        <h5>Re: Wedding Annoucement!</h5>
                        <p>
                            Huh! Waw!!! I'm really excited to celebrate with you all. Thanks for...
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <div class="badge">12</div>
                        <img class="icon" src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/Mail128.png"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tile double image-slider" data-role="tile-slider" data-param-period="5000" data-param-direction="left">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/1.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/2.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/3.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/4.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/5.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="tile-group tile-drag">
                <div class="tile image outline-color-green">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/myface.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tile-group tile-drag">
                <div class="tile bg-color-blue icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/InternetExplorer128.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Internet Explorer</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/excel2013icon.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Excel 2013</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/word2013icon.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Word 2013</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/onenote2013icon.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">OneNote 2013</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tile double image-set">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/1.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/2.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/3.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/4.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/5.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Photos</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tile-group">
                <div class="tile double image">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/4.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand bg-color-orange">
                        <img class="icon" src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/Rss128.png"/>
                        <p class="text">This is a desert eagle. He is very hungry and angry bird.</p>
                        <div class="badge">10</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile bg-color-blue icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/InternetExplorer128.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Internet Explorer</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/excel2013icon.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Excel 2013</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/word2013icon.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Word 2013</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/onenote2013icon.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">OneNote 2013</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tile-group tile-drag">
                <div class="tile double image">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/4.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand bg-color-orange">
                        <img class="icon" src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/Rss128.png"/>
                        <p class="text">This is a desert eagle. He is very hungry and angry bird.</p>
                        <div class="badge">10</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile bg-color-blue icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/InternetExplorer128.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Internet Explorer</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/excel2013icon.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Excel 2013</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/word2013icon.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Word 2013</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile icon">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/onenote2013icon.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">OneNote 2013</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tile-group">
                <div class="tile quadro double-vertical image-set">
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/1.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/2.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/3.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/4.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile-content">
                        <img src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/5.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="brand">
                        <span class="name">Photos</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a href='http://hit.ua/?x=19154' target='_blank'>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!--
    Cd=document;Cr="&"+Math.random();Cp="&s=1";
    Cd.cookie="b=b";if(Cd.cookie)Cp+="&c=1";
    Cp+="&t="+(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset();
    if(self!=top)Cp+="&f=1";
    //--></script>
    <script language="javascript1.1" type="text/javascript"><!--
    if(navigator.javaEnabled())Cp+="&j=1";
    //--></script>
    <script language="javascript1.2" type="text/javascript"><!--
    if(typeof(screen)!='undefined')Cp+="&w="+screen.width+"&h="+
            screen.height+"&d="+(screen.colorDepth?screen.colorDepth:screen.pixelDepth);
    //--></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!--
    Cd.write("<img src='http://c.hit.ua/hit?i=19154&g=0&x=2"+Cp+Cr+
            "&r="+escape(Cd.referrer)+"&u="+escape(window.location.href)+
            "' border='0' wi"+"dth='1' he"+"ight='1'/>");
    //--></script>
    <noscript>
        <img src='http://c.hit.ua/hit?i=19154&amp;g=0&amp;x=2' border='0'/>
    </noscript></a>
<!-- / hit.ua -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried updating my jquery library as mentioned in the link. But still no luck. Any other steps you suggest ?

Comment: 1 - <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

2 - <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

3 - <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tile-slider.js"></script>

Which script among the 3 are you not able to consume ? is it a winJS   app that is one meant for tablet devices or a web project ?? if you clear these then it might be helpful to proceed. :)

Comment: It is a website am working on. and it is <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tile-slider.js"></script> from metroui.org am trying to consume. I am able to use Js/Jquery plugins for other websites was just wondering what could be the problem with this one alone.

Comment: Please look into the code i see that it is consuming using the online api. Please check for paths problem in Local.

Comment: It is so weird that the code isn't working with the local copy of js file (verified the path more than once) . Tried this solution it is working now. Thanks a ton man !

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't clear at all..
If I understood right, your problem may be that the row:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tile-slider.js"></script>
```

is in the head tag. Try moving it to just behind the end of body tag. Try moving every script that is not working to there. Some things in javascript won't work if the script is in the wrong place- that's because if the script is in the beginning, it's read before the html is read. If you're trying to change something in the html, for example, it won't do that if it comes before that html row. If it doesn't work please add the script source.

Comment: I tried that but dint work anything other suggestions?.. the issue here is not being able to use tile-slider.js by including it in the html file

Comment: I believe the right answer is the other one.. Try moving the html tags as it says.

Comment: yes tried that but couldn't solve the issue. i even tried adding all the .js code under <script> </script> tags no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your html tag is in the wrong place - it should look something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- script and link tags go here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- div and img tags go here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case all you want is to show flipping tiles, you could use the jquery `animate` function as follows:

```
// hides the given tile, and calls the callback.
this._hideTile = function(tile, callback){
    tile.animate({height:0});
}

// shows the given tile.
this._showTile= function(tile){
    tile.animate({height:150});
}
```

Check out the full logic in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mWdL/27/).